# Programmatically finishing business process flow in Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am managing the whole CRM process flow in C# code, using the newest SDK version (8.2). Moving forward works fine, simply by updating the stageid on the relevant entity.
However I have no idea, how could I finish the last stage = how could I set process to finished. I'd like to call exactly the same actions as with clicking the button "set finished"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the current status of the active process instance to *finished* use:

```
Xrm.Page.data.process.setStatus("finished");
```

---

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn817878.aspx#BKMK_setStatus):

```
Xrm.Page.data.process.setStatus(status, callbackFunction);
```

`status` is a string that can be `active`, `abandoned` or `finish`. `callbackFunction` is an optional function to call when the operation is complete.

**Note:** though the documentation says to use `finish` this does not work: use `finished`.

Comment: Thanks Dave. My bad - I have not explicitally written that I would like to do it using C# (Custom Action). I've editted the question.
Still the solution you suggest could be used in my case as workaround.

Comment: The anwser is almost correct. It seams that there is a mistake in the Documentation. Working call:
Xrm.Page.data.process.setStatus("finished");

Comment: In Doc there is also a status "abandoned" which real name is "aborted"

Comment: You're right. I've just tested this myself on Dynamics 365 (8.2.0.798): `finish` did not work whereas `finished` did work!

Answer (score 3):

When you create a business process flow you create a custom entity. For example, if you create a business process flow called *Marketing Management* in the default solution, you will create an entity called *new_marketingmanagement*.

When you activate a business process flow on a record, an instance of that entity is created. The instance holds information such as which stage the process is at and when the process was started.

You can deactivate the instance using [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.SetStateRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest.aspx):

```
var stateRequest = new SetStateRequest 
{
    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(processFlowName, processId),
    State = new OptionSetValue(1), // Inactive.
    Status = new OptionSetValue(2) // Finished.
};
service.Execute(stateRequest);
```

Where `processFlowName` is the logical name of your business process flow as a string and `processId` is the ID of the process flow instance you want to deactivate as a GUID.

To find the ID of your process flow instance, you can query the attribute `_bpf_<primary_key>_value` where `<primary_key>` should be replaced with the primary key of the entity which your process is on. For example on the Account entity this would read `_bpf_accountid_value`.